# How to release an NSMutable Array which we need to use in return statements

Tags: iphone, sqlite, memory-leaks, retain, autorelease

IM USING SQLITE DATABASE for my iPhone app

In my app in data base to retried the content from the database i used an array and i return this array in a database method for select statement,

for this purpose i allocate an array and i need to release the array,

```
NSMutableArray *allContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 return allContacts;
```

if i release an array how sh'd i used in return statement

viceversa if i tried to release after return (we can do anything after return)

Any solution please....

How should we use auto release NSMutable array

```
//Select statement for contacts
//==================================
+ (NSMutableArray*) selectAllContactsFromDB
{
      NSString *DBPath = [self copyDBFile];
      sqlite3 *contactsDB = nil;
      sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
      NSMutableArray *allContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      if (sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &contactsDB) == SQLITE_OK)
      {
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT ROWID, NAME, MOBILE,  FROM CONTACTINFO"];
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactsDB, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                  while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                  {
                        Contact *contact = [[Contact alloc] init];
                        contact.rowid = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                        contact.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                        contact.mobile = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];


                        [allContacts addObject:contact];
                  }
            }
            else {
                  NSLog(@"Statement not prepared");
            }
      }
      [DBPath release];
      return allContacts;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return an allocated object from a method pass it as an `autoreleased` object.

```
return [allContacts autorelease];
```

When you get an `autoreleased` object you need to `retain` it for further use:

So change the calling method like;

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[YourClass selectAllContactsFromDB] retain];
```

Comment: It seems that what i want exactly, but I have a small doubt that, when eve we used retain in NSMutableArray *temp = [[YourClass selectAllContactsFromDB] retain]; the ratain count again increase to 1?

Comment: when you call the retain on an autoreleased object it's retain count will be same as before calling autorelease. Means if the object's retaincount was 1 when you call autorelease and retain it's retaincount will be same no increment. It'll be 1

Comment: @user1811427: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
NSMutableArray *allContacts = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

and also like this..

```
return [allContacts autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write return statement 
`return [allContacts autorelease];`
OR you can use `ARC` in your project.

Answer (score 1):

use ARC(Automatic Reference Counting) or you have a property as a mutuable array and just return the array...

to get u started on ARC, watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxuI4e_Bj58

Comment: but im now at the ending stage of my app , how  shd i use ARC at middle of app

Comment: arc is either enabled for the whole app or not? so there is no middle... edited the question... in the case use autorelease

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `autorelease` :

```
return [allContacts autorelease];
```

This way il will be released the next time the autorelease pool will be flushed. And you have followed the golden rule : For each `alloc`, `copy` or `retain`, you must have a `release` or `autorelease`.